# Taking a class and making a new class that is object oriented (python)

Tags: python, oop

I have to figure out a way to take a code that was already given and improving it by making it  a class that is object oriented.

This code: was already given and we use it for our new code. the file 'students2txt' is being extracted line by line (being split based on a ':') and the `StudentFileReader` class is imported into the new `class StudentReport(object)`. And so the finished project is supposed give a student list that has ID numbers, first and last names, gpa's (all information is give in the 'students2.txt' I just have to make the code print all of the info.

`filereader.py`:

```
class StudentFileReader:
    def __init__(self, inputSrc):
       self._inputSrc = inputSrc
       self._inputFile = None

    def open(self):
       self._inputFile = open(self._inputSrc, 'r')

    def close(self):
       self._inputFile.close()
       self._inputFile = None

    def fetchRecord(self):
       line = self._inputFile.readline()
       if line == "":
          return None

       record = StudentRecord()

  #change
       record.idNum = int(line)
       record.firstName = self._inputFile.readline().rstrip().rsplit(':')
       record.lastName = self._inputFile.readline().rstrip().rsplit(':')
       record.classCode = int(self._inputFile.readline())
       record.gpa = float(self._inputFile.readline())

       return record

class StudentRecord:
    def __init__(self):
       self.idNum = 0
       self.firstName = ""
       self.lastName = ""
       self.classCode = 0
       self.gpa = 0.0
```

New file:

```
from filereader import StudentFileReader


class StudentReport(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self._theList = None
   def loadRecords(self, filename):
       self.reader = StudentFileReader(filename)
       self.reader.open()

       theList = []
       record = self.reader.fetchRecord()
       while record is not None:
           theList.append(record)
           record = self.reader.fetchRecord()

       reader.close()
       return theList

   def sortByid(self):
       self._studentList.sort(key = lambda rec: rec.idNum)

   def sortByName(self):
       pass

   def __str__(self):
       classNames = [ "", "Freshman", "Sophomore", "Junior", "Senior" ]




       print( "LIST OF STUDENTS".center(50) )
       print( "" )
       print( "%-5s  %-25s  %-10s  %-4s" % ('ID', 'NAME', 'CLASS', 'GPA'))
       print( "%5s  %25s  %10s  %4s" % ('-' * 5, '-' * 25, '-' * 10, '-' * 4))

   # Print the body.
       for record in theList :
            print( "%5d  %-25s  %-10s  %4.2f" % \
                 (record.idNum, \
                  record.lastName + ', ' + record.firstName,
                  classNames[record.classCode], record.gpa) )
   # Add a footer.
       print( "-" * 50 )  
       print( "Number of students:", len(theList) ) 



if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = StudentReport()
    s.loadRecords('students2.txt')
    s.sortByName()
    print str(s)
```

This code was taken from the textbook Data Structures and Algorithms Using Python. I'm supposed to make an object oriented class. I've started the `StudentRecord` class and written the `__init__` but I'm not really sure what to do after that. When I try to run anything it gives me a `invalid literal for int() with base 10` error. I'm very new to python so I'm not sure how to make any class object oriented easily..

edit: yes, the error came from the fetchRecord function

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\...\studentreport.py", line 24, in <module>
  s.loadRecords('students2.txt')
File "C:\Users\...\studentreport.py", line 13, in loadRecords
  record = self.reader.fetchRecord()
File "C:\Users\...\filereader.py", line 22, in fetchRecord
  record.idNum = int(line)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10015:John:Smith:2:3.01\n'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line parsing code doesn't match the format of the file.

You are trying to interpret the *whole line* as an integer, but the line contains more.

Perhaps you wanted to split the line first? That one line contains *all* elements of the record:

```
parts = line.strip().split(':')
record.idNum = int(parts[0])
record.firstName = parts[1]
record.lastName = parts[2]
record.classCode = parts[3]
record.gpa = float(parts[4])
```

You can *override* the original `StudentFileReader.fetchRecord())` method by subclassing the class in your own code:

```
class MyStudentFileReader(StudentFileReader):
    def fetchRecord(self):
        line = self._inputFile.readline()
        if not line:
            return None

        record = StudentRecord()

        parts = line.strip().split(':')
        record.idNum = int(parts[0])
        record.firstName = parts[1]
        record.lastName = parts[2]
        record.classCode = parts[3]
        record.gpa = float(parts[4])

        return record
```

Then use `MyStudentFileReader()` instead of `StudentFileReader()`.

Comment: ah, so making a list first and then using the int and float based on the position of the list?

Comment: @HK: Yes, the `.split()` returns a list; then you can access individual elements and apply conversions as needed.

Comment: also, in def loadRecords(self, reader) of the StudentReport, I got back an error saying that the global name filename was not defined?

Comment: Your posted code has a `filename` argument for that method; did you replace that with `reader`?

Comment: I tried to fix it but if I put filename, it says that reader is not defined and if I put reader, it says that filename is not defined

Comment: @HK: look at the code you posted here; there you have `self.reader = ..`, but the last line is `reader.close()`; you simply forgot to add `self.` there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your line before you start trying to convert the pieces into the formats you want for your individual data items. Right now, you're calling `readline` repeatedly, so each of the values you're calculating for a student comes from a separate line from the file.

Instead, try splitting and unpacking the result directly into local variables:

```
idNum, firstName, lastName, classCode, GPA = line.rstrip().split(':')
```

Then do whatever conversions each of those need (e.g. `record.idNum = int(idNum)`).

Comment: that seemed to get rid of the 'int' error. So after that, I ended up getting another error that said that  int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'